# How to rebuild project after changing a node module for React Native

Tags: android, react-native, node-modules

I am modifying a specific node module (react-native-keychain) for android, but I am not sure if changes are affecting yet. What is the procedure to rebuild the project? - Will these just work or am I doing something wrong? (I am using a real device)

- npm install
- npm start
- react-native run-android

Thanks

For reference, this is what I want to achieve: 
https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain/issues/337#issuecomment-728191068

Also, it is: "react-native": "0.63.2", so linking is not required

Answer (score -1):

A rebuild will usually consist of re-install packages, re-link as necessary, then fire off the build/run script.

However, there are a lot of factors that influence the correct approach.

For example, is your development OS Mac, Windows or Linux? Is your project Expo managed, or is it full React Native.

I would suggest you take the awesomely comprehensive React Native docs as a starting point:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device

If that doesn't do it, look in the side panel of that site for additional information -- you might want to start with the section entitled 'The Basics' and take it from there.